# Displaying local time from ISO 8601 string with Momentjs

Tags: datetime, momentjs, iso, iso8601, localtime

I want to display the local time from an ISO 8601 string using momentjs. 
There is a discrepancy of minutes when I convert an ISO string using different date formats. If I use 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm', the minutes is correctly displayed. If I use 'ddd, MMM Do HH:MMa', 11 minutes is added (in my case).

My sample js (babel) code:

```
let today = moment('11/09/2016 00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').toISOString();
//today = 2016-11-09T08:00:00.000Z

let formatted = moment(today, moment.ISO_8601).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm');
//formatted = 11/09/2016 00:00

let formatted2 = moment(today, moment.ISO_8601).format('ddd, MMM Do HH:MMa');
//formatted2 = Wed, Nov 9th 00:11am
```

I would prefer using the second format. Can someone explain why there is a discrepancy?

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anudhagat/8fgtjbc7/3/

Answer (score 2):

I caught my silly mistake. I have capitalized the minutes in the second format, using MM makes it display months instead of minutes.